# Open a webpage in the default browser with specific size in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want my users to be able to click a button to open my company webpage in the default browser with specific size(Like-width=SomeSize,height=SomeSize')when clicked. How would I do this?

I'm using VB.net so all .net examples are acceptable.

Comment: Open it **FROM WHAT**?...another webpage?...a WinForms app?...a WPF app?...a Console app?...

Comment: i want when user click About Button(In my Vb.Net App) Open my about Page(like-about.html) in user default browser but open windows size 500(width) and 300(height)Like in html-function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");  // Opens a new window
}

Comment: "In my Vb.Net App"...again, what TYPE of app are you creating?  Maybe WinForms?  If so, I'd recommend you simply drop a WebBrowser control on a Form so you can easily open an instance and set a size for it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in whatever browser the user has installed would be very difficult. Each browser has its own command line arguments, so you would have to detect which browser is being used, and code for all possible browsers..

If you are willing to have windows open the page in Internet explorer, you could use add a reference in your solution explorer to the windows Shell Document Viewer.

To do this, in your solution explorer window, right-click on "References".

Click "Add Reference". This opens the "Reference Manager" window

In the window that opens, down at the bottom right click the button "Browse"

In the file dialog, in the file name box type "C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll" without quotes.

Click the "Add" button. and the dialog should close, leaving you with the "Reference Manager" window.

In this window, in the list in the middle, you should see "shdocvw.dll" with a tick next to it. Click the "Ok" button.

You now have a reference to the Shell Document Viewer

Finally, add the following code to wherever you want the window to open and change the parameters to whatever you require

```
    Dim TheBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium With {
        .Visible = True,
        .Width = 500,
        .Height = 500
    }
    TheBrowser.Navigate(URL:="http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com")
```